JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings does not contain SerializerSettings in v. 11
I have a SwaggerUi3 implementation like this
app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(Startup).Assembly, settings =>
{
    settings.Path = "/api/v1/swagger";
    settings.DocumentPath = "/api/v1/swagger/swagger.json";
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    settings.GeneratorSettings.SerializerSettings = serializerSettings;
    settings.GeneratorSettings.SchemaType = NJsonSchema.SchemaType.OpenApi3;
    settings.GeneratorSettings.Title = "MyProject";
    settings.GeneratorSettings.Version = "v1";
    settings.GeneratorSettings.UseErrorResponse<ApiErrorResponse>();
    settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new LowercaseDocumentProcessor());

    settings.GeneratorSettings.UsePolymorphism(o => {
        o.UseBaseClass<ConnectorConfigDtoBase>(x => x.Discriminator);
        o.UseBaseClass<TargetConfigDtoBase>(x => x.Discriminator);
        o.UseBaseClass<FilterConfigDtoBase>(x => x.Discriminator);
    });

    settings.GeneratorSettings.AddOperationFilter(ctx =>
    {
        return ctx.OperationDescription.Path.StartsWith("/api/v1");
    });
});

But when I update NJsonSchema to version 11  I cant add this
settings.GeneratorSettings.SerializerSettings = serializerSettings;
How to solve that problem
JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings.SerializerSettings is removed
